# How to use MySQL stored function argument to refer to column name?

Tags: mysql, functions

How can I use a function argument s to stand in for a column name in a query?  I'm using mysql 5.5.  I tried

```
SELECT count_distinct(last_name)
```

but it returns

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'last_name' in 'field list'
```

The function was defined as

```
CREATE FUNCTION count_distinct (s CHAR(20) )
RETURNS INT
READS SQL DATA
RETURN( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT s) FROM president);
```

I expected it to return a value of 37 as

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT last_name) FROM president
```

returns 37. 
The 'president' table is from the sampdb database from [MySQL by Paul Dubois](http://www.kitebird.com/mysql-book/).

Comment: You'll need to use dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 1):

With thanks to Colin 't Hart this worked:

```
DELIMITER $
CREATE PROCEDURE showUnique( IN col CHAR(64))
BEGIN
SET @s=CONCAT('SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ',col,') FROM president);
PREPARE stmt from @s;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END $
delimiter ;
CALL showUnique(last_name)
```

Comment: It works, but it shouldn't be done.  Objects aren't data and data isn't objects.  Crossing that boundary reeks of bad design and introduces potential security vulnerabilities.  Try running `CALL showUnique('1) UNION ALL SELECT user FROM mysql.user); #');`, for example.

Comment: Thanks.  How should it be done, then?